# how to animate remove background after hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i want the right way to remove background after setting it when mouse over an element,

i tried these :

```
$("#store_header .right #nav ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor : '#0097d5'}, 200);}
    ,function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor : ''}, 200);
    }

);
```

but second function didn't work , so please tell me what's the error and what's the right

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a color to revert , check ***[the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jNUPU/)***. (note: included jquery-ui)

```
$("#store_header .right #nav ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor : '#0097d5'}, 200);
    } ,function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor : '#fff'}, 200);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7WMS/)

```
$("#store_header .right #nav ul li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor : '#0097d5'}, 200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor : 'transparent'}, 200);
    }
);
```